# The usage of articles with the word right and only

Tags: articles

Very often, the article THE goes with the words RIGHT and ONLY. When is it OK to use A?

Examples:

- This is a difficult question. Is there a right answer to it? (I think it's correct)
- This is a difficult question. Is there the/an only one right answer to it? (Not sure)
- This is a difficult question. However, there is a right answer to it. (I think it's correct)
- This is a difficult question. However, there is the/an only one right answer to it. (not sure)
- This is a difficult question. There is not a right answer to it. (I think it's correct)
- This is a difficult question. There is not the/an only one right answer to it. (not sure)

Comment: *There is **a** right answer* is valid, but *There is **the** right answer* wouldn't normally be (except in peculiar contexts that probably aren't worth bringing up here). And since etymologically speaking ***a / an*** are just alternative versions of ***one***, it's normally *There is [only] **one** right answer* (but again, there are unusual contexts where *There is **only the** right answer* would be natural). But native speakers probably wouldn't say many if any of your examples - but note that *Is there a single [unambiguously] correct answer to this question?*  is perfectly natural.

Comment: (...except there ***isn't***, obviously! :)

Comment: ...but *there is **a** marked general tendency* to avoid the definite article [after ***Is there***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28Is+there+a%29%2B%28Is+there+an%29%2CIs+there+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28Is%20there%20a%29%20%2B%20%28Is%20there%20an%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CIs%20there%20the%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C(Is%20there%20a)%20%2B%20(Is%20there%20an)%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CIs%20there%20the%3B%2Cc0)...

Comment: ...and after [***There is***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28There+is+a%29%2B%28There+is+an%29%2CThere+is+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28There%20is%20a%29%20%2B%20%28There%20is%20an%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CThere%20is%20the%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C(There%20is%20a)%20%2B%20(There%20is%20an)%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CThere%20is%20the%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1):

1. *Is there a right answer to it?* is natural and normal

2a. *Is there the* is incoherent, because *is there* is not normallyused to refer to definites.

2b. *Is there only one right answer to it?* is fine.

3. *There is a right answer to it* is grammatical, but unusual, because it does not logically add anything beyond "there is an answer to it". So it gets used when the speaker is inviting the hearer to consider several possible answers, and particularly if the hearer has already suggested some answers which were not right.

4a. *There is the right answer to it.* is again odd because we don't use *there is* with definites.

4b. *There is only one right answer to it* is natural, when drawing attention to the fact that there are no other alternatives.

5. *There is not a right answer to it* is fine.

6a. *There is not the right answer to it* is not normal again

5b. *There is not only one right answer to it* is grammatical, and implies that there are several right answers.